# React Native 0.57.2 build issue: Could not find support-annotations.jar (com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1)

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native

I'm hitting a build issue with a fresh `react-native init` project (*RN 0.57.2*) when starting up with `react-native run-android`:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> What went wrong:
>
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
>
> Could not find support-annotations.jar (com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1).
>     Searched in the following locations:
>         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-annotations/27.1.1/support-annotations-27.1.1.jar

What could possibly be wrong here? Is my Android Support Library version installed by Android Studio wrong?

I'm running *Android Studio 3.1.0.0* on WIN10, *yarn* version 1.10.1.